# deleting records from sqlite on the basis of date in android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I want to delete some records from android's database where two conditions are fulfilled. 
1. there's a column with the name as sync_status, it should have a value 'C' and
2. there's column which has date.

Now I want to delete only those rows where sync_status is = 'c' and date is less than device's current date. I'm having problem in comparing the device's current date with the date stored in the database and my function deletes all the records.

```
public int RemoveSyncData(){

      DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context); 
      DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy ");
      Calendar calObj = Calendar.getInstance();
      String currentDate = dateFormat.format(calObj.getTime());
      Log.e("current date",currentDate);

      int rows = db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE_DAILY_ATTENDANCE, KEY_ATTENDANCE_SYN_STATUS + "= ? and " + KEY_ATTENDANCE_DATE_ONLY + " != '" + currentDate + "'", new String[] {"C"});

      db.close();
      return rows;
}
```

Comment: If you were storing the date as a simple `long` value (like you get from `System.currentTimeMillis()`), this would be far simpler. Perhaps you can change how you store the date?

Comment: I'm storing the date in string.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I'm suggesting it would be easier **not** to store it as a string, but as a simple `long` instead. Storing it as a string makes it difficult to do comparisons like the kind you want to do in your question.

Comment: @Anita can you tell in which format are you storing the date in database ? i.e `dd-MM-yyyy` ..  etc ?

Comment: @SharpEdge in string format

Comment: @Anita String format i know.. but can you tell an example? like what i ask `dd-MM-yyyy` or `MM-dd-yyyy` ? I know its String but which date style in String.. ?

Comment: @SharpEdge oh sorry, I'm storing date in this format in database DateFormat dateFormatOnly = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");

Comment: Part of the problem with the current approach is that you cannot use the value as input to some of SQLite's date and time functions, because `MM-dd-yyyy` is not a format those functions recognize as input. If it were, then at least you could do some trickery in the selection clause to make the dates comparable. Again, I highly suggest you switch to storing simple `long`s for the time; it's easy enough to convert the long to or from a formatted date using `Calendar` and formatting classes.

Comment: @Anita check my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you absolutely want to keep the date as a string in the form `MM-DD-YYYY` in your database column, then the only way to do comparison of those dates is to convert them to seconds using SQLite's `strftime` function. However, in order to do that, you have to restructure the date as `YYYY-MM-DD` because your current format is not one that can be used as input to the date and time functions of SQLite.

Here is a sample:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
Calendar calObj = Calendar.getInstance();
String currentDate = dateFormat.format(calObj.getTime());

String where = KEY_ATTENDANCE_SYN_STATUS + " = ?1 AND "
        + "STRFTIME('%s', SUBSTR(" + KEY_ATTENDANCE_DATE_ONLY + ",7) "
        + "|| '-' || SUBSTR(" + KEY_ATTENDANCE_DATE_ONLY + ",1,5)) < "
        + "STRFTIME('%s', SUBSTR(?2,7) || '-' || SUBSTR(?2,1,5))";
String[] whereArgs = {"C", currentDate};
int rows = db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE_DAILY_ATTENDANCE, where, whereArgs);
```

If you use `yyyy-MM-dd` when creating `currentDate`, you can replace the second instance of the ugly substring + concatenation with just `STRFTIME('%s', ?2)`, but you will still need the first substring + concatenation to transform the column values in the table.

If it's not too late for you to change how your database stores the date, make your life easier by either storing as `yyyy-MM-dd` (to get rid of all the substring + concatenation above), or better yet store the `long` date and only worry about converting it to and from `MM-dd-yyyy` at the java layer.

Comment: please take some time and answer my question   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32396140/how-to-convert-a-hash-table-in-string-in-java

Answer (score 0):

** **EDIT** **

Your condition is right it should delete only the rows that meet the condition, just tested it on my SQLite Viewer with some dummy data..

Just be 100% sure that your variable names match the column names and also check the database, if there are some rows which shouldn't be deleted. Maybe there is no entry for today's date and "C" is present in all rows thats why all the records are being deleted.

You can also try the "not so good way":

```
db.execSQL("delete FROM tableName WHERE KEY_ATTENDANCE_SYN_STATUS = 'C' AND KEY_ATTENDANCE_DATE_ONLY != '"+currentDate+"'");
```

The above is not a good way as `execSQL` won't return anything so you won't have anyway to know if it was successful except for checking it yourself.

The above approach is only to test your condition though.

Comment: `!=` and `<>` are both valid operators that mean "not equals".

Comment: Well, as far as I have seen, `!=` and `<>` behave exactly the same in SQLite. If you can provide a case where they do not, I'd certainly like to know about it.

Comment: @Karakuri You're rite, my bad.. Just found that it has to do something with encoding and ANSI. I'll Edit my answer.