# How to convert a hash table in string in Java

Tags: java, hashtable

I'm new in Java and I want to convert a hash table in the form of a string, with each pair separated by any special character. How can I apply loop on the hash table and extract values from?

```
 public String parseHashtable(Hashtable detailHashtable){
     
    String hashstring= "";
    foreach(){
    hashstring += key + "=" + hashtable[key] + "|";
    }
     return hashstring;
 }
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: @vish4071 yes that is what i need. how to apply condition in for loop

Comment: Note you might want to use a `StringBuilder` for concatenating strings.

Comment: Ok. I guess you have answers that solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String seperator = "|";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

Set<String> keys = detailHashtable.keySet();
for(String key: keys) {
    sb.append(key+"="+detailHashtable.get(key)+ seperator);
}

return sb.toString();
```

Comment: my mistake, it should be `detailHashtable` instead of `hm`. I have changed it.

Comment: not working. the string is showing very different values and not the values which i have in hash table

Comment: What object types are your `key` and `value`

Comment: Can you post the values that you are getting vs the ones you should be getting

Answer (score 4):

You can use Map.Entry as follows:

```
 String hashstring= "";
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : hashTable.entrySet()) {
        hashstring += entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue() + "|";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public String parseHashtable(Hashtable detailHashtable){

    String hashstring= "";
    for(Entry<String,String> entry : detailHashtable.entrySet()){
        hashstring += entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue() + "| ";
    }

    return hashstring;  
}
```

Comment: foreach does not seem java... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Both the `HashMap` and `HashTable` can use `Map.Entry` to get both key and value simultaneously.

```
String hashstring= "";
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : detailHashtable.entrySet()) {
    hashstring += entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue() + "|";
}
```

Refer the API to know what operations can be used. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#entrySet()

Comment: It is giving an error Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to Map.Entry<String, String>

Comment: I assumed that your key and value is String. Change the data type as you require. What's the key and value type of your HashTable?

Answer (score 0):

`Map` from which `Hashtable` extends provides the method `Map.entrySet()`, which returns a set containing all entries in the map.

```
for(Map.Entry e : detailHashTable.entrySet()){
    Object key = e.getKey();
    Object value = e.getValue();

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use **entry.getKey().to String()** and **entry.getValue().toString()**;