# Android SQLite RawQuery not returning records with 2017 date

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a database that contains upcoming births.  The file has 5 records in it with due dates of (11-15-2016,10-15-2016, 12-14-2016, 12-13-2016 and 02-12-2017)
The query is

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String QueryPart1="SELECT inseminations._ID, inseminations.patient_id, inseminations.date_due ";
        String QueryPart2="FROM inseminations ";
        String QueryPart3="WHERE inseminations.date_due>=? ";
        String QueryPart4="ORDER BY inseminations.date_due ASC";
        String FinalQuery=QueryPart1+QueryPart2+QueryPart3+QueryPart4;
        mCursor = db.rawQuery(FinalQuery ,howToFilter);'
```

howToFilter is

```
            String howToFilter[]={ExpectedDateDue};
```

ExpectedDateDue is

```
        ExpectedDateDue = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").format(new Date());
```

The query retrieves all records except for the one from 2017, the listview is sorted correctly, it's as if the query is only taking those records where the month is after the current month instead of the entire date.

Comment: When you put the month first, the values are sorted by month.

Comment: With a yyyy-MM-dd format it will work

Comment: When I change the format to yyyy-MM-dd no records are returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparison operators on text in SQLite use lexicographic order. What this means, for example, is `"01-01-2017`" is *less than* `"05-04-2016"`. SQLite has no indication that these strings represent moments in time that should be compared chronologically.

In general, I dislike using strings for timestamps in my databases for reasons like this. I much prefer to store timestamps as long values representing seconds (or milliseconds) since epoch. It's far easier to compare timestamps this way, and converting to and from date strings is simple enough either in SQLite or in Java.

If that's not feasible for some reason, then I suggest you alter the way you store your date strings in the database. Instead of `MM-dd-yyyy`, use `yyyy-MM-dd`. In this format, lexicographic comparisons will work; using the same example as before, `"2017-01-01`" is *greater than* `"2016-05-04"`. Additionally, this format is acceptable as input to SQLite's various [date and time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), should you decide to use them.

If you can't alter the way the dates are stored, you will need to somehow convert them into a format that is comparable in the way you expect. You could use SQLite's `substr()` and `||` (concatenation) functions in the query to convert the date from `MM-dd-yyyy` to `yyyy-MM-dd` format. The code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32369208/1207921) demonstrates this.

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a try